# How to properly test .net service logic

Tags: c#, testing

I have a functioning test but I need guidance how to properly test the logic. My understanding of testing is that it should be done without tight coupling to the resources (which is where mocking comes in) but if everything is mocked (especially the return result) how can the logic be tested, properly, without instantiating a bunch of classes?

`ValidateEmployeeConfigurationAsync` (below) will return `RulesValidationResult` which is what I want to assert. So I can answer my own question of how, which would require newing up repositories and services - that's one way. Is there a best practice way to accomplish that? That feels wrong.

#### Functioning Test

```
  [TestMethod]
  public async Task PassValidateEmployeeConfigurationTest()
  {
        //ARRANGE
        const long employeeId = 200L;
        const int configurationTypeId = (int) Constants.Configuration.ConfigurationTypes.User;
        const bool enabled = true;

        _ruleService = new Mock<IRuleService>();
        _configurationService = new Mock<IConfigurationService>();          
        _ruleFacade = new Mock<IRuleFacade>();

        _configurationService.Setup(x => x.GetByConfigurationNameAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(GetConfigurations(enabled));

        _ruleService.Setup(x => x.GetConfigRulesByEmployeeIdAsync(It.IsAny<long>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(GetRules(enabled));

        _ruleFacade.Setup(x =>
                x.ValidateEmployeeConfigurationAsync(It.IsAny<long>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(GetPassedValidationResult());

        //ACT
        var result = await
            _ruleFacade.Object.ValidateEmployeeConfigurationAsync(employeeId, "TestConfiguration", configurationTypeId);

        //ASSERT
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, result.PassedValidation);
  }
```

#### Method of interest

```
  public async Task<RulesValidationResult> ValidateEmployeeConfigurationAsync(long employeeId, string configurationName, int configurationTypeId = 6)
  {
        var key = GetDefaultKey(configurationName);
        var rules = new List<Rule>();
        var validationResult = new RulesValidationResult();
        validationResult.Messages.Add("Configuartion not found", configurationName);

        var configurations = await _configurationService.GetByConfigurationNameAsync(configurationName);

        if (!configurations.Any())
            return validationResult;

        var configuration = configurations.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ConfigurationTypeId == configurationTypeId);
        rules = await _ruleService.GetConfigRulesByEmployeeIdAsync(employeeId);

        if (rules.Any() && configuration.ConfigurationSettings.Any())
        {
            var testTargets = new List<ConfigurationSetting>();
            testTargets.AddRange(from setting in configuration.ConfigurationSettings
                where setting.IsActive && setting.Key == key
                select new ConfigurationSetting
                {
                    ConfigurationId = setting.ConfigurationId,
                    Key = setting.Key,
                    Value = setting.Value
                });

            if (PassesRules(testTargets, rules))
            {
                var msg = $"{configurationName} passed rule validation";
                validationResult.PassedValidation = true;
                validationResult.Messages.Clear();
                validationResult.Messages.Add("Passed", msg);
            }
            else
            {
                var msg = $"{configurationName} failed rule validation";
                validationResult.Messages.Clear();
                validationResult.Messages.Add("Failed", msg);
            }
        }

        return validationResult;

  }
```

Comment: Because typically your tests care about the data itself, not where it comes from. You set up your tests to have certain expectations--e.g. when inputs are 2 and 2 , I expect the result to be 4--and executing the test confirms or denies those expectations. You mock out the dependencies and fix the data so that you are *only* evaluating the logic.

Comment: The 'Act' of the test calls a method on a mock object - that definitely isn't right. The act should be calling your real code. The mocks should only be replacing the *dependencies* of the code being tested, not the code itself. You should only need to setup the behaviour of those dependencies, not the thing you call in the 'Act', which should be the *structure under test*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I structured the test, view the previous version of the `TestMethod` to see the differences. In the original question, the test would always pass given the incorrect way the test was structured.

In this version, the input is mocked, the dependencies are mocked, and the IOC container is setup so the targeted code is tested and the assertion can be applied to the generated output.

```
  [TestMethod]
  public async Task PassValidateEmployeeConfigurationTest()
  {
        //ARRANGE
        const long employeeId = 200L;
        const int configurationTypeId = (int) Constants.Configuration.ConfigurationTypes.User;
        //need the IOC container 
        var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

        //Mock ALL the dependencies (services and repositories)
        var ruleFacade = new Mock<IRuleFacade>();
        var employeeConfigMapRepo = new Mock<IEmployeeConfigurationMapRepo>();
        var ruleRepo = new Mock<IRuleRepo>();
        var ruleService = new Mock<IRuleService>();
        var configurationService = new Mock<IConfigurationService>();
        var employeeConfigurationService = new Mock<IEmployeeConfigurationService>();
        var organizationConfigurationService = new Mock<IOrganizationConfigurationService>();
        var facilityConfigurationService = new Mock<IFacilityConfigurationService>();
        var configurationSettingService = new Mock<IConfigurationSettingService>();

        // configure the dependencies so that the proper inputs are available
        configurationService.Setup(x => x.GetByConfigurationNameAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(GetConfigurations(true));

        employeeConfigMapRepo.Setup(x => x.GetAllByEmployeeIdAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(GetEmployeeConfigMaps(true));

        employeeConfigurationService.Setup(x => x.GetAllByEmployeeIdAsync(It.IsAny<long>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(GetEmployeeConfigMaps(true));

        ruleRepo.Setup(x => x.GetByConfigurationIdAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(GetRules(true));

        ruleService.Setup(x => x.GetConfigRulesByEmployeeIdAsync(It.IsAny<long>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(GetRules(true));

        // help the IOC do its thing, map interfaces to Mocked objects
        unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IRuleService>(ruleService.Object);
        unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IRuleRepo>(ruleRepo.Object);
        unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IConfigurationService>(configurationService.Object);
        unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IEmployeeConfigurationService>(employeeConfigurationService.Object);
        unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IOrganizationConfigurationService>(organizationConfigurationService.Object);
        unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IFacilityConfigurationService>(facilityConfigurationService.Object);
        unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IConfigurationSettingService>(configurationSettingService.Object);
        unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IRuleFacade>(ruleFacade.Object);

        // thanks to all the mocking, the facade method ValidateEmployeeConfigurationAsync can now be tested properly
        var ruleHelper = unityContainer.Resolve<RuleFacade>();

        //ACT
        var result = await
            ruleHelper.ValidateEmployeeConfigurationAsync(employeeId, _testConfigName, configurationTypeId);

        //ASSERT
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, result.PassedValidation);
    }
```